# Не меняется list на tuple

Tags: javascript, python

Есть работающий код для решения [fizz-buzz](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz):

```js
python(`
r = [[15, 'fizzbuzz'], [3, 'fizz'], [5, 'buzz'], [1, '']]

for x in range(1, 33):
  for y,m in r:
    if x % y == 0:
      print(m or x)
      break
`)

function python(code) {
  with ({
    list: Array.from,
    *range(l, r, s=1) { for (r ?? (r=l,l=0); l<r; ++l) yield l },
    print: console.log,
  }) {
    eval(code
      .replace(/[ \t]+$/g, "")
      .replace(/^( *)(?:( +).*\r?\n)(?=(?: *\r?\n)*\1(?![ \r\n]))/gm, (m,s,d) => m + d.replace(/  /g, "}"))
      .replace(/^ *(\w+)(.*):\s*$/gm, (m,x,t) => { try { eval(`var ${x}`); return m; } catch { return `${x}(${t}):` } })
      .replace(/:\s*$/gm, "{")
      .replace(/\b((?=\w+,)[\w,]+\s+)in\b/g, '[$1]of')
      .replace(/\bin\b/g, 'of')
      .replace(/\band\b/g, '&&')
      .replace(/\bor\b/g, '||')
    )
  }
}
```

Хочу в нём переменную `r` сделать списком tuple'ов, но не получается - код запускается, никаких ошибок не происходит, но и ответ не выводится:

```js
python(`
r = [(15, 'fizzbuzz'), (3, 'fizz'), (5, 'buzz'), (1, '')]

for x in range(1, 33):
  for y,m in r:
    if x % y == 0:
      print(m or x)
      break
`)

function python(code) {
  with ({
    list: Array.from,
    *range(l, r, s=1) { for (r ?? (r=l,l=0); l<r; ++l) yield l },
    print: console.log,
  }) {
    eval(code
      .replace(/[ \t]+$/g, "")
      .replace(/^( *)(?:( +).*\r?\n)(?=(?: *\r?\n)*\1(?![ \r\n]))/gm, (m,s,d) => m + d.replace(/  /g, "}"))
      .replace(/^ *(\w+)(.*):\s*$/gm, (m,x,t) => { try { eval(`var ${x}`); return m; } catch { return `${x}(${t}):` } })
      .replace(/:\s*$/gm, "{")
      .replace(/\b((?=\w+,)[\w,]+\s+)in\b/g, '[$1]of')
      .replace(/\bin\b/g, 'of')
      .replace(/\band\b/g, '&&')
      .replace(/\bor\b/g, '||')
    )
  }
}
```

PS: С 1 апреля!